# Hide mounted drives from Gnome favorites bar

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, manjaro

After updating my Gnome Desktop Environment to version 3.34.1, whenever I mount a device, it will be shown in the favorites bar (as seen in the image below).

I don't want any of my mounted devices here. How can I disable this function? I tried to find an option to disable it in *settings* and *gnome tweaks* but did not find anything.

By the way, I'm using Manjaro 18.1.1, with Gnome 3.34.1 and my kernel version is 4.14.149.

[image: gnome favorites bar]

Thanks.